# How show Multidimensional Arrays be inserted into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

In this table, I have the fields 'title' 'url' 'keywords' and description that I want data entered into. By the way, all the fields i have are 'id', 'title', 'description, 'keywords' url' and 'rank' in that order. I basically want to input data from a multidimensional array into the mysql table and for every array, with [title] and [url] etc. I want it to be one row. 
My code is below:

```
 $data = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
$output = array(
  "title"       => Titles($link), 
  "link"        => $link,
  "description" => getMetas($link),
  "keywords" => getKeywords($link) 
    );
   if (empty($output["description"])) 
  {$output["description"] = getWord($link);
  }
  $data[] = $output;
  }
 print_r($data);  

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO scan (title, url, description, keywords) VALUES ('".implode("'),('",$data)."')");

if (!mysql_query()) {
echo "woops";
 }

  mysql_close($connect);
```

Just to be clear, I want to array above, in my MYSQL table.

Comment: is your data printing correct result..??

Comment: You should insert json instead of the array

Comment: use more than one table?

Comment: I'm just wondering whether anyone who has commented tried to understand the question.. the query part shows clearly what OP wants to achieve, the title is misleading.

Comment: Move into the 21st century, look at using prepared statements with mysqli or pdo

Answer (score 1):

That depends, because you would have to do a table in the database with time,date,competition,first_team,second_team columns

It really depends on how much you know at the moment, if you just want to log a plain array you can just serialize it into the database and unserialize it in the code

e.g. 
php Code:

```
$array = array ('one','two','three'); 
$array = serialize ($array);
var_dump ($array);
$unseralize = unserialize ($array);
var_dump ($unserialize);
```

Something tells me you might want to just put it over the database and query the server then do the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize and send it to db
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Just thought of sharing info: [Read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#107717)

Comment: sounds good but in such cases you have to use it. Like when you going to add some data that contain  "add more" button to add second, third or so on stuff...

Comment: Why should he serialize anything? Did you even read the code posted?