# Why won't this Array Insert into my MYSQL table?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How show Multidimensional Arrays be inserted into a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596528/how-show-multidimensional-arrays-be-inserted-into-a-mysql-table)

I have an array. The array is multidimensional and works fine in regards to being imploded. Then when I make an attempt in order to insert the array into the database, each multidimensional array, per row. It won't go in. Only the final row inserts itself, but after trying this new code, which doesn't insert anything, I am stuck. By the way, I have lost the previous code:

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output = array(
        "title"       => Titles($link), 
        "link"        => $link,
        "description" => getMetas($link),
        "keywords" => getKeywords($link) 
    );
    if (empty($output["description"])) {
        $output["description"] = getWord($link);
    }
    $data[] = '"' . implode('" , "', $output) . '"';
}
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO search (title, description , keywords, link)
    VALUES (" . $data . ")" );
```

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question at least 3 times over the last couple of days, posted from different user accounts... this is incredibly bad coding practise. Move into the 21st century: use prepared statements with MySQLi or PDO rather than this atrocity of bad SQL building with the deprecated MySQL interface.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are assigning the result of `implode` to `$data[]`, i.e. the next available array element of `$data`. In this case, you want to assign the result of `implode` to just `$data`.

If you print the generated SQL, you would probably just get `INSERT INTO ...... VALUES(Array)`.

Answer (score 0):

the query `mysql_query( "INSERT INTO search (title, description , keywords, link)
    VALUES (" . $data . ")" );` needs to be inside the `foreach` loop.

```
     foreach ($links as $link) {
$output = array(
    "title"       => Titles($link), //dont know what Titles is, variable or string?
    "link"        => $link,
    "description" => getMetas($link),
    "keywords" => getKeywords($link) 
);
if (empty($output["description"])) {
    $output["description"] = getWord($link);
}
$data = '"' . implode('" , "', $output) . '"';
$success = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO search (title, description , keywords, link)
VALUES (" . $data . ")" );
if( $success)
  echo $link . ' row inserted';
 }
```

Comment: if you intend to concatenate `Titles` and variable `$link`,then the `output` array needs to be `$output = array(
    "title"       => 'Titles' .$link, 
    "link"        => $link,
    "description" => getMetas($link),
    "keywords" => getKeywords($link) 
);`

Answer (score 0):

Your INPUT syntax only populates one row.
To add all the rows in one MYSQL query you would change the code as follows:

```
$data = "";
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output = array(
        "title"       => Titles($link), 
        "link"        => $link,
        "description" => getMetas($link),
        "keywords" => getKeywords($link) 
    );
    if (empty($output["description"])) {
        $output["description"] = getWord($link);
    }
    $data .= '("' . implode('", "', $output) . '"), '; // add each row in parenthesis.
}
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO search (title, description , keywords, link)
    VALUES " . $data );
```

Also, your mysql code has all been deprecated, and you should convert over to mysqli as soon as you can.